# finding unique names before saving in c# and sql server

Tags: unique, handle, names

i have to handle unique names and save it in db like -

If name already exists, find the smallest number you can append to the name to save it as a unique name.

For example:
    If username Scott already exists, save as Scott(1). If Scott(1) already exists, save as Scott(2). Etc.

i am using c# and sql server 2010

any great ideas ?

Comment: What programming language and database type are you using?

Answer (score 0):

figured that out - but appreciate improvements

```
            var seprator = "scott";

        var list = new List<string>();

        list.Add("scott");
        list.Add("scott(1)");
        list.Add("scott Alex");
        list.Add("scott (4)");
        list.Add("scott(xxx)");
        list.Add("scott(250)");
        list.Add("scott(12s)");
        list.Add("scott(123)x");
        list.Add("Scott caps");
        list.Add("Alex Scott caps");
        list.Add("xxxscottmmm");


        var numberList = new List<int>();

        foreach (var v in list)
        {
            var parts = Regex.Split(v, seprator, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

            if (parts.Length > 1)  //(1) Alex (4) (xxx) (250) (12s) (123)x caps caps 
            {
                var secondPart = parts[1].Trim();

                if (secondPart.StartsWith("(") && secondPart.EndsWith(")"))  // (1) (4) (xxx) (250) (12s)
                {
                    var valuebetweenbraces = secondPart.Substring(1, secondPart.Length - 2);  //1 4 xxx 250 12s 

                    int number;
                    var isNumber = int.TryParse(valuebetweenbraces, out number);

                    if (isNumber)
                    {
                        numberList.Add(number);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        int maxValue = 0;

                    if (numberList.Count > 0)
                        maxValue = numberList.Max() + 1;
                    else
                        maxValue = maxValue + 1;
                       Response.Write(seprator + "(" + maxValue  + ")");
```